# https://api.parse.com/crossdomain.xml not found error

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I'm using parse platform for unity3d game development. And I receive 404 not found error when

I try to run the game in safari web player on facebook canvas.

Looking into console gave me the error 404 on https://api.parse.com/crossdomain.xml

But the same thing perfectly works on chrome and firefox, though when I try to open the xml file directly using url in chrome incognito it still can't be found.

Has anybody met something like that or knows how to fix it ?
Thxs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it just be an error on Parse's side?  I'm getting the same issue, never seen it before.  Looks like the file just doesn't exist.

Comment: Might have spoken too soon, looks like there's a file up now.  Maybe they were just updating it?

Comment: And it's broken again...  Might have to email them if it keeps this up.

Comment: Yeah they really seem to have some problems. All requests from my unity editor also started to fail. I have reported a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested. 
Are you using any third party plugins?
Some plugins do not work with certain browsers.

Try checking if there is any 'web-site root' that you had given in the program.

Comment: Situation is specific to parse.com and has nothing to do with my plugins, because the same crossdomain.xml file is returned by parse servers or not returned with 404 status code, depending on some conditions I am not aware of.